# Making a button in indesign go to a specific page in exported PDF

Tags: pdf, navigation, adobe-indesign

In InDesign I can define buttons and can add different actions to them. One of these actions is "go to page", but apparently that function is only usable when exporting the InDesign document as an SWF. However, we want to export an interactive PDF.

When we open the exported PDF in Adobe Acrobat Professional we can touch up each and every button in the document and set the page to the page we want, but this is of course extremely tedious work, especially when you have several proving runs.

So, my question is: how do I get my buttons in InDesign to jump to a specific page without having to do the touch up late in Adobe Acrobat Professional? Surely it must be possible to navigate between pages?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I stumbled on this issue a while back too, and i figured out how to link to a place in an interactive PDF document via Buttons:

1) Create Bookmarks on the pages you want to link to. (I usually make a text in the top of the page in 'paper color' and create a bookmark from that)

2) Button action "Go to destination" -> Bookmark

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, that is working fine. We found that we have to put the anchor across the whole page, so that no unnecessary zooming is done when switching, but apart from that it now works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Make a box in inDesign. 
Select the box. 
Open Hyperlink panel 
"Create a hyperlink destination" I use the page number 
Then go to the page in your inDesign document where you want to make the button. 
Make a box and select it
Open hyperlinkpanel "Make hyperlink" and choose the destination you made using the pulldown (not the page number counter, that didn't work for me).

Answer (score 1):

interactiv->Hyperlink and You choose "New Hyperlink destination" from menu in top-right dropdown menu. And choose page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sometime but now i know the deal (on **CS5** on Windows). I only have the German version so maybe i´ll label some things wrong:

When you create your button and determine the "action" you´ll get a list with available options. Here the upper options work in PDF and SWF, but some options are available "only in swf" and "only in pdf.

"Go to a certain page" is not available in PDF :( 
So you have to edit the document via Acrobat.

Another thing: When writing an interactive pdf-file use the option "Export..." under "File", here you chose "Adobe PDF (Interactive)" under filetype.

**Maybe** (as a thought) there is a way to use Javascript in InDesign and/or Acrobat to assign the buttons automatically.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the conclusion we've come to, but it is highly frustrating. If the functionality can be done in Acrobat, why can it not be done in InDesign? That makes no sense whatsoever. And with a 60 page document with 14 buttons on each page, 12 of which need to be corrected, you are looking at 720 buttons to correct...

Comment: Although Adobe-Products work pretty well, i have a long list of "why´s". If you come across a working solution please let me know.